# centering "bootstrap navbar li items" on all page width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to center li items "on all page width" in this basic bootstrap navbar which I shared.

I tried "justify-content-center" in the parent. It centered the navbar items but not in all page width. Items should be on left little bit.

I check too many questions but can't figure it out. I also add another example to clean the case.

https://codepen.io/canerucal/pen/YzEgVKr

https://jsfiddle.net/4y5tscum/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

edit: the goal is taking nav items to true center as shown like below.

[image]

edit2: I want to align these two items to the page center but due to flex I can not.

desired output:
[image: problem]

result:
[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `text-center` class to the `ul`.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 justify-content-center  me-4" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav me-5">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: nothing is changed when i add text-center. li items still not on "true center"

Comment: @piseynir please provide a markup image of your desired solution. The end goal is not clear, the `li`'s are centered on desktop and mobile for the menu in the snippet.

Comment: I edited the question. If you check my two examples, center items are not on center truely. Because of navbar logo/brand, items going to right.

Comment: @piseynir See edits, this what you mean? It's not "true center" due to default padding.

Comment: I edited the question detailly. You can see the result and desired output now.

Comment: @piseynir See edits, that's probably your best bet. LMK if you have questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242636/discussion-between-piseynir-and-).